# Tensorflow 2.4 - DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, tensorflow, dll

I use TensorFlow 2.4 on Windows 10 with Python 3.8 (I have Python 3.9 and 3.6 installed too) within a virtual environment `ml2u` where only TensorFlow 2.4 is installed so far by `pip install tensorflow`. I get the error messages below by trying to import TensorFlow in a notebook. As recommended in other posts I have installed Microsoft visual C++ redistributable which led to the installation of MS Visual and `VC_redist.x64.exe`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\scripts\ml2u\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\scripts\ml2u\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\scripts\ml2u\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context

c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\scripts\ml2u\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\scripts\ml2u\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

----

The shell produced followint output while running jupyter:
[W 20:51:12.010 NotebookApp] Notebook Untitled.ipynb is not trusted
[I 20:51:14.060 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0d0455bd-ade8-4128-b273-0b24e8d9228f, name: ml2u
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this issue because you are running 32-bit python or 32-bit OS. And also check does your CPU supports AVX instructions.

Please take a look at [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) and check if you have correct dependencies installed.